# Detecting class toggle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do an off-canvas sidebar and I am using the `.toggleClass` function to make it active or not. When it is active I would like the button (.btn) to say "hide" and when it is not say "show". I have already tried to do an if statement and it has failed. I have also looked at other stackoverflow questions with no success. Can anybody help with how to detect a class has been toggled or not?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');

    // if active "hide"
    $('.btn').html("HIDE");

    // if not active "show"
    $('.btn').html("SHOW");

  });
});
```

Comment: If the `.btn` is inside or next to the `.row-offcanvas`, I'd just use CSS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.hasClass('someClass')` will help you to retrieve a *boolean* `true/false`

> <sup>[api.jquery.com/hasclass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass):</sup> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.  The .hasClass() method will return `true` if the class is assigned to an element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    var act = $('.row-offcanvas').hasClass("active");

    if(act){
       $('.btn').html("HIDE");
    }else{
       $('.btn').html("SHOW");
    }
  });
});
```

a shorter way using a [Conditional Operator (AKA Ternary operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) would be:

```
$(function() {  // DOM ready

   $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').on("click", function () {
     var $row = $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
     $('.btn').html($row.hasClass("active") ? "HIDE" : "SHOW");
   });

});
```

Also I have to warn you that by selecting elements like `$(".btn")` will alter **every single** `.btn` element on the page. Make always sure to use the right selectors with the help of `.find()` (or similar Selector methods). for specificity sake.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder did that already ;) But sure, smaller = more fun :)

Comment: Or even: http://pastie.org/9803880 But that's a pain to debug. :-) Your edit just now is absolutely how I'd do it.

Answer (score 2):

You should have another way to select your objects, for example by id, as follows:

```
$("#myid")...
```

Then you can use the hasClass function (http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to verify if the class has already been added to the object.

```
$("#myid").hasClass("xxx")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    if ($('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active').hasClass('active'))
      $('.btn').html("HIDE");
    else 
      $('.btn').html("SHOW");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this. You just need to add an if/else statement to check the class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
 $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');

  if ($('.row-offcanvas').hasClass('active')){
    $('.btn').html("HIDE");
   }
  else{
   $('.btn').html("SHOW");
   }

 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/Lmfok39k/

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript by checking the element classList Like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("elementId");
el.classList.contains("foo");
```

More information in [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)